# Conditionally hiding specific window from desktop screenshot

Tags: c#, windows, hide, screenshot

Is this possible. I have three (3) windows:

- Window1 - not active
- Window2 - not active
- Window3 - active

If I take the screenshot of the desktop I want `Window3` to be hidden quietly. Provided the user is using `Window3` the program must not in any way hide the windows like minimizing it or anything. In short, I need an unobtrusive way of hiding specific windows from desktop screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to be possible without quite a bit of work. The print screen functionality just copies the contents of the desktop DC to an image and places it on the keyboard. It doesn't actually re-render the whole desktop into a new DC. So there's no way that it can silently remove a particular window.

I suppose you could hook the print screen button (or the function, whatever it is) and allow it to create the image on the clipboard. Then your hook could read the location of the window in question from the desktop and clear out that area of the bitmap that's on the clipboard.

Your hook would do this:

```
call the normal print screen function
load image from clipboard
get location and size of Window3 from desktop
fill that rectangle in the image with black (or whatever)
put the modified image back on the clipboard
```

Assuming, of course, that you can hook the print screen function. I suspect it's possible, although I've never tried it.

Comment: thought of that however not the black part. I don't want a black rectangle but a whole picture

Comment: @Aivan: You want to show what's "behind" Window3? I think you're going to discover that what you're asking is exceedingly difficult, if at all possible.

Comment: well I have thought of a solution but im looking for other easier solutions. This is my take. get screenshot of every window and its position. get screenshot of taskbar. get screenshot of desktop. then combine them into one picture. exclude unecessary windows.

Comment: For every window you'll need its screenshot and its place in the z-order. And you might have some difficulty with non-rectangular windows, or windows that are not 100% opaque. I'm going to put this in the "exceedingly difficult" category.